# How to load the drill down pie chart in highcharts in same position of the parent chart?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, charts, highcharts

How to load the drill down pie chart in highcharts in same position of the parent chart?
[Please find the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7F85.png)

Please see my current code below:

```
    var chart;
        function BindChart(seriesArr) {
            var UNDEFINED;
            Highcharts.setOptions({
                lang: {
                    drillUpText: '<< {series.name}'
                }
            });
    
    
            Highcharts.chart('topIssueContainer', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'pie',
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    height: 180,
                    marginLeft: 0,
                    events: {
    
                        drilldown: function (e) {
                            
                            if (!e.seriesOptions) {
                                chart = this;
                                //alert(e.point.ID);
                                chart.showLoading('Loading Details ...');
                                $('#hdntopIssueID').val(e.point.ID);
                                var dataArr = CallChild(e.point.ID, e);
                                chart.setTitle({
                                    text: ''
                                });
    
                                //setTimeout(function () {
                                //    chart.hideLoading();
                                //    chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, data);
                                //}, 2000);
                            }
                        }
                    }
    
    
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false,
                            format: '{point.name}',//: {point.y:.1f}%
                            useHTML: true,
                        }
                    },
                    pie: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false,
                            useHTML: true,
                            style: { fontSize: '8px', textDecoration: 'none' },
                        },
                        showInLegend:true,
                        size: 110,
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function () {
                                    if (this.drilldown != true) {                          
                                        CallGrid($('#hdntopIssueID').val(), this.series.name, this);
    
                                    }
    
                                }
                            }
                        }
    
                    },
                },
                legend: {
                    align: 'right',
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    //itemmarginRight: 10,
                    x: -30,
                    y: 0,
                    itemStyle: {
                        fontWeight: 'initial',
                        fontSize: '10px'
                    },
                    symbolRadius: 0
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b> of total<br/>'
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Top Issues',
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: seriesArr,
                }],
                drilldown: {
                    drillUpButton: {
                        relativeTo: 'container',
                        position: {
                            y: 0,
                            x: -5
                        },
                        theme: {
                            fill: 'white',
                            'stroke-width': 1,
                            stroke: 'silver',
                            r: 0,
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    fill: '#a4edba'
                                },
                                select: {
                                    stroke: '#039',
                                    fill: '#a4edba'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }
            });
    
            $('#topIssueContainer span').css({ 'text-decoration': 'none' });
        }
```

In CallChild function I'm justing posting the data like below. But the chart is going right side when drill down happens. It should the on the same place as the parent chart.

```
    function CallChild(ID, e) {
        var Drilldowndata = [];
        var url = path + "GetBucopitalDrilldownview";
        var dData = {
            "LevelId": ID,
            "LevelName": "test",
            "Type": "topIssue",
            "associateId": associateId,
            "color": "red"
        };
    
        var Token = sessionStorage.UserToken;
        //$("#loaderImage").addClass("in").css({ "display": "block" });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            headers: { "UserToken": Token },
            dataType: 'json',
            data: dData,
            success: function (Result) {
                //debugger;
                //Result = Result.d;
    
                for (var i in Result) {
                    var serie = { name: Result[i].LevelName, y: Result[i].FTECount, procCount: Result[i].ProjectCount, LevelId: Result[i].LevelId };
                    Drilldowndata.push(serie);
                }
                data = {
                    name: e.point.name,
                    data: Drilldowndata
                }
    
    
                chart.hideLoading();
                chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, data);
            },
            error: function (Result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        })
        return Drilldowndata;
    }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Could you please include some more detail such as what technology you're using and how you are producing the chart?

Comment: Hi, We are using Jquery-ajax to bind the chart from a web API